# How to use semicolons in bash function oneline declaring

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 2 questions:

1)
having this multiple-line bash function:

```
somefunction() {
 do some stuff
 innerfunction() {
  do some stuff
  return 1
 }
 do more stuff
}
```

The problem here is, When the script enter the inner function and returned, the outer (original) keeps executing, which should not (once returned), I do not know why.

2)
If I declare one-line function
say:

```
$ func() { faill() { echo fail; return 1 } echo abc }
```

I do not know whether to give semicolon after last statement in inner function (last statement - `return 1`), but when I press enter to save the function, it still waits for the end  (so I have to sigterm'd it).
if I do

```
$ func() { faill() { echo fail; return 1; } echo abc; }
```

That is - added semicolon after `return 1` and `echo abc` - then
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'echo'`

So can some please give a clue of how the bash interprets semicolon (I though `;` == `\n`)

Comment: There is no inner function scope in Bash, unless you trick it with declaring the outer function with parenthesis (sub-shell context) rather than curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to separate the function definition from the following command.

```
func() { fail() { echo fail; return 1; }; echo abc; }
#                                       ~
```

Note that `fail` will remain accessible outside of `func` after `func` has run.

Comment: To have the inner `fail()` function only valid within the `func`, use a sub-shell function like this: `func() (fail() { echo fail; return 1; }; echo abc)`

Comment: why is the function body in parethesis `()` and not in braces `{}`?

Comment: To run in a subshell. But then you can't set any global variables from within the body.

Comment: yout function does not return, why when inner function does have `return`? Neither does output `fail` as should does inner function

Comment: Parenthesis creates a sub-shell. Curly braces are optional. The full syntax would be: `func() {(fail() { echo fail; return 1; }; echo abc)}`

Comment: @Herdsman: You need to actually call a function to run it. Declaration doesn't run a function.

Comment: Creating subshell is not what I asked for. I wanted to keep env vars set, only use compound function. There are still 2 question not answered- 1)your inner function does not output `fail` in `echo fail`, 2) your function does not return after `return 1`

Comment: @Herdsman: Your questions make little sense. To see `fail` in the output, you need to call the inner function, e.g. `func() { fail() { echo fail; return 1; }; echo abc; fail; }`. Without running the inner function, you're just declaring it for later use.

Comment: why is there need for 2 semicolons: `1; };` the first one does not make sense, as end-close-brace should end the function body. Neither does the second semicolon, as that is semicolon after body, that does not make sense even more. Is there a rational behind that?

Comment: @Herdsman The end close brace does *not* end the function body. `{` and `}` are only treated specially when they appear in command position. Without the `;`, `}` is just another (unexpected) argument  to `return`.

Comment: @chepner what do you meant by  `are only treated specially`, how does bash treats it? If it is not end of body, what else?

Comment: Consider the function `foo () { echo }; }`, which is syntactically correct and outputs the single character `}` when called. You need to terminate the final command with a semicolon, `&`, or newline before the parser can recognize `}` as the closing brace of the command group, rather than another argument of the final command.